# Probability to get the same cards in a card game two times

Tags: probability, card-games, bernoulli-numbers

I want to calculate the probability to get a set of cards two times in a card game, respectively how many two times I would have to play to get it with a specific probability. The card game is "Schafkopf" which is very popular in Germany: It's played with $32$ cards and $4$ players, so every player gets 8 cards. I assume that there are $\pmatrix{32\\8}$ permutations, so the probability is $\frac{1}{\pmatrix{32\\8}}$ which is about $10 000 000$. For the formula I use a Bernoulli-chain (don't know if that's the English name; It's this one: $$P^n_p(X=k)=\pmatrix{n\\k}\cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$$
I hope you know what I mean). 
Assuming that $p = \frac{1}{\pmatrix{32\\8}}$ my formula would be:
$$P^n_p(X=2)=\pmatrix{n\\2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{n-2}$$

Is this formula correct? Or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Are you trying to find the probability of getting a specific hand twice, or just the probability of a duplicate?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate? I want the probabilty to get a hand in a game, and get that hand later in another round again. They do not have to be one after another, just some times later.

Comment: Is André's answer below answer your question?  Or do you have something else in mind.  Your comment immediately above suggests the possibility of playing a few rounds on a given day, and you don't care if the two identical hands appear in consecutive rounds on any day.  Can you be more precise about the exact situation you want to determine the probability of?

Answer (score 1):

First we give a precise version of the problem. We play the game twice. The probability that we get the same cards in both games is indeed $\frac{1}{\binom{32}{8}}$, which is about $9.5\times 10^{-8}$.

For simplicity call this number $p$.

The next day we again play the game twice, and then we play the game again twice the next day, and so on for $N$ days. We want to find the number $N$ of days we must play so that with probability $a$ we get the same cards twice on at least $1$ day.

The probability we get the same cards at least twice is $1$ minus the probability we get the same cards $0$ times on the $N$ days. And the probability we get the same cards $0$ times is $(1-p)^N$. So we want
$$1-(1-p)^N=a,$$
or equivalently 
$$(1-p)^N=1-a.$$
Take the logarithm (say the natural log, but it doesn't matter). We get
$$N\log(1-p)=\log(1-a),$$
and now we know $N$.